# i want to set border color for gridpane and change font color for the text inside the gridpane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

```
    String[] tableTitleList = {" Title", " (Re)set", " Obs", " Mean", " Std.Dev", " Min", " Max", " Unit"};
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    List<String> tabTitleList = Arrays.asList(tableTitleList);
   for (int i = 0; i < countList.size(); i++)
   {
   paneList.add(FlowPaneBuilder.create().maxHeight(850).maxWidth(500).style("-fx-border-color: white;").build());
        tableList.add(GridPaneBuilder.create().
                columnConstraints(new ColumnConstraints(100), new ColumnConstraints(65),
                        new ColumnConstraints(65), new ColumnConstraints(65), new ColumnConstraints(65),
                        new ColumnConstraints(65), new ColumnConstraints(65)).
                rowConstraints(new RowConstraints(40), new RowConstraints(40)).
                visible(true).gridLinesVisible(true).
                build());
```

}

i want to change the border color of the gridpane and color of the text inside the gridpane. all gridpane is added into the panelist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the border color you could use this : applyStyles('border: solid 1px red');

For the text : setTextFill('Your Color')

Comment: i think we don't have any such commands in javafx. could be a little clear

Comment: i used       tableList.get(i) to get the gridpane from the list. for this gridpane i need 2 set a border color and change the font color for the text.

Comment: You have such command in javafx : for the text check : https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavafx%2F2%2Ftext%2Fjfxpub-text.htm&ei=K8aFU6_QJofiPPOzgMAL&usg=AFQjCNEde9AJid-ol0xir7XZjAvZhmB3hQ&sig2=Um7Y1dC74_Tz-BBv9Iu_Nw and for the border http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288995/how-to-add-border-to-panel-of-javafx ( you only need to change CSS )