# JavaFX Border Title

Tags: css, javafx

[image]

This above picture is result of my code.But I want like the following.
[image]

How can I fix it? The following is my code.I read too many sources but they was too complicated. For example,[a source that I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288995/how-to-add-border-to-panel-of-javafx), I think this way is very complicated.Maybe there is a easy way to solve this problem.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    public BorderPane border = new BorderPane();

    public Label name = new Label("Name");
    public Label surname = new Label("Surname");

    public TextField name1 = new TextField();
    public TextField surname1 = new TextField();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 300, 200);
        arg0.setTitle("Header");
        arg0.setResizable(false);
        scene.setFill(Color.OLDLACE);

        StackPane grid = addStackPane();
        border.setMargin(grid, new Insets(12,12,12,12));
        border.setCenter(grid);

        ((VBox) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(border);
        arg0.setScene(scene);
        arg0.show();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public StackPane addStackPane() {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        Label title = new Label("Border Title");
        title.setStyle("-fx-translate-y: -7");
        pane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        grid.setStyle("-fx-content-display: top");
        grid.setStyle("-fx-border-insets: 20 15 15 15");
        grid.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
        grid.setStyle("-fx-border-color: black");
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 10, 25, 10));
        grid.add(name, 1, 0);
        grid.add(name1, 2, 0);

        grid.add(surname, 1, 1);
        grid.add(surname1, 2, 1);
        pane.getChildren().addAll(grid, title);

        return pane;
    }

}
```

Thank you all that reads this topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set `-fx-background-color` of your title label to the same color as the borderPane's background. And make sure you set in a css file, because it's  not possible to set multiple styles via `setStyle()` unless you concatenate them:

```
myComponent.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: white;"+
    "-fx-background-color: black;");
```

Furthermore it is bad practice to use an InlineStyleSheets as it always has a higher priority than a rule specified in a CSS StyleSheet.

(If you change `pane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_LEFT)` to `StackPane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_LEFT)` you can remove the "static-acces" warning.)

Answer (score 1):

User [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea) has made a control to perform this.

The related stackoverflow question is: [How to add border to panel of javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288995/how-to-add-border-to-panel-of-javafx)

And on gitHub: https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2838292

I have used it with minimal modification and it works like a charm.