# adding border title in JavaFX

Tags: java, css, javafx-8

I'm having trouble trying to implement the use of a **Border Title in JavaFX** so that can show the **panel**, already searched the forum and found some **identical questions** [JavaFX Border Title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412885/javafx-border-title) but is **not quite explicit on how it was resolved**, it was not necessary to put the code **for is a logical and theoretical doubt** as will be implemented in order to achieve the ultimate goal will be to show the panel in accordance with its implementation and I think maybe there is a another solution to solve this doubt

[image]

any suggestion?

Comment: Also, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288995/how-to-add-border-to-panel-of-javafx

Comment: @BileshGanguly, thanks