# How to create LEGEND (text in chart border) in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, javafx-3d

How add text in pane border in JavaFX like this:

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough to answer it. Which chart border do you mean? Normal JFX 8 Charts? They generate their own legends. Or do you want a styled TextField?

Comment: I use JavaFX8..

Comment: I don't think the question is about the legend. More about bordered pane and such a question had been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288995/how-to-add-border-to-panel-of-javafx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to a node they have in `c#`. I don't know if `JavaFX` has this type of node. In `SceneBuilder` I added a border around a `Pane` and a `Label` on top of the border. I then set the root `AnchorPane`'s background to white and the `Label`'s background to white. I did not try this with `Group` but I am guessing it might be a good idea.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: White;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Pane fx:id="pane" layoutX="200.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-border-color: BLACK;" />
      <Label layoutX="218.0" layoutY="92.0" style="-fx-background-color: WHITE;" text="Label" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]